# Theme "seven" – how to allow regular users edit content with this theme?

Tags: theming

please instruct me how to allow regular users (non-admins) to use Seven theme to edit content. Now users are forced to edit content using the default drupal theme which wasn't designed for this purpose (looks ugly).
Is it matter of some permission? Admins are editing with Seven theme without problem.

I've found some topics about more complex cases with module recommendations like this:
http://drupal.org/project/themekey . As my case is pretty simple, I decided to ask!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the permissions "View the administration theme" fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Administration Theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module to control which pages are rendered with the admin theme (in your case: Seven).

Comment: Ok, so I checked again permissions table (which got pretty complex thanks to a lot of modules and content types) and search one more time for "theme" (few results, confusing similar titles) ... ended up turning on "View the administration theme" which did the trick! :)

Comment: Aha, good catch, I forgot that that's a separate permission. Did you can add your own solution as answer and mark it as accepted (in a day or two)?

Comment: sure. I will do that!